# AngularJS Select index of selected property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have a request that returns an array of objects based on a Provider selected. Like this:

```
data:[
    0:
        Producto:"Chiken",
        Unidad: "box",
        PrecioUnitario:"34334",
        etc..
    1:
        Producto:"Chiken",
        Unidad: "box",
        PrecioUnitario:"200",
        etc..
]
```

I'm displaying the data properly in a `<select>` tag
[image: Example]

What I want is that if the user selects let's say "Carne Asada" all of the other properties of that selected child object are auto-selected on the rest of the fields, i.e:

Unidad text input should be "box" automatically, "precioUnitario" field should be 200.
Or visually:
[image]

Another thing is that it should display the value that the object has but it can be edited by the user.

Controller:

```
$scope.columns = [{colId: 'col1', producto:[], catidad:'', unidades:[], preunit:''}];
$scope.fact = {};

$scope.get_proveedor_prod = function(fact){
  var data = {ProveedorID: fact.ProvID};
  $http.post(URL + "/api/get_prod_by_provider.php",data).then(function(callback) {
      $scope.products = callback.data;
  }); 
}
```

View:

```
<md-input-container>
  <select ng-model="fact.producto"
  ng-options="item.ProductID as item.NombreProducto for item in products"
    class="form-control selectformcc" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Producto</option>
  </select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: did you mean `data: [...]`?  You wrote `data: {...}` which is not an array.  Your edit is still not valid code because the array can't have keys like that.  Do you mean  `[{Producto:"Chiken",Unidad: "box",PrecioUnitario:"34334",},{...}]`?

Comment: Yes @sh0ber let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming your data notation is incorrect and that you meant to use an array of objects.)

Bind the `select` to the whole item instead of to a property of the item:

```
ng-options="item as item.NombreProducto for item in products"  //not ="item.ProductID...
```

Now `fact.producto` (`select` model) is an object and will contain the whole item.  In your Unidad text box you can use:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fact.producto.Unidad" />
```

Here is an example with easy to understand data:  [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/e0pLtky1/)